# How to detect if the user has clicked on "Quit" in a zenity list

Tags: bash, zenity

This is my code:

```
while true; do
    choice=$(zenity --list --text "Users are listed below." --title "Result" --ok-label="Back to Menu" --cancel-label="Quit" --column=Users $(cut -d : -f 1 /etc/passwd))
    if [ "$choice" = "root" ]
        then    
            echo 'You have clicked on root'
    fi
    if [["$?" = "Quit"]]
        then
            exit
    fi
done
```

As you see, It first shows the list of active users on the system. I want my tiny program to print "You have clicked on root" if the user has clicked on "root" and do something else if he/she has clicked on the buttons (including "Quit" and "Back to menu").

Note: I have searched a lot and i know there are tons of questions which are related. But none of them has a precise answer to my question.

Edit: I changed my code and now the problem is that it doesn't echo anything.

```
while true; do
choice=$(zenity --list --text "Users are listed below." --title "Result" --ok-label="Back to Menu" --cancel-label="Quit" --column=Users $(cut -d : -f 1 /etc/passwd))

if [ "$?" != 0 ]
then
    exit
fi

if [ "$choice" = "root" ]
then    
    echo 'You have clicked on root'
fi
done
```

I'm not sure if it's related or not. But I'm using ubuntu 18.04

Edit 2: I ran my script using bash -x and the result is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Zsgk4RCdTZ/).

Comment: Line 233 in your result is the output `You have clicked on root`

Comment: @muru You're right! I'm going to accept your answer :) Thank you for the time you spent on my question :) I'm really grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$?` is the exit status, which is an integer and can never be "Quit". But, if the user did click on "Quit", zenity will exit with status 1, and 0 if the user clicked the OK button.

```
$ choice=$(zenity --list --text "Users are listed below." --title "Result" --ok-label="Back to Menu" --cancel-label="Quit" --column=Users $(cut -d : -f 1 /etc/passwd))
# clicked Quit
$ echo $?
1
```

So you could do:

```
choice=$(zenity --list --text "Users are listed below." --title "Result" --ok-label="Back to Menu" --cancel-label="Quit" --column=Users $(cut -d : -f 1 /etc/passwd))

if [ "$?" != 0 ]
then
    exit
fi

if [ "$choice" = "root" ]
then    
    echo 'You have clicked on root'
fi
```

It's better to compare with `0`, since other failure conditions may result in exit status other than 0 or 1.

Comment: Thank you :) But if add my while loop again, the "echo" command does not show anything. What's the problem?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzadeh works fine for me. Please edit your question to show your updated code.

Comment: Ok, I did what you said :)

Comment: @ArmanMalekzadeh The updated script still works fine for me. please run your script with `bash -x` to debug it and the output to the post.

Comment: I'm new to bash. How should i use this command?

Comment: Run your script like `bash -x my-script.sh` (Or whatever your script filename is instead of `my-script.sh`).

Comment: I used sh my-script.sh to run it. I changed the command to what you wrote. Please see my edit.